# Creating a custom post type, adding custom meta fields, preventing all future editability of posts of this type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, custom-field

I am new to plug-in development and have ran into a bit of a speed bump.

So here are my criteria, I am pretty much struggling to tick off any of them:

I wish to create a custom post type 'website' - This bit I can do!

I require only three fields, two of which are custom meta fields (title, website_url & website_source_code) - The extra fields, I believe are being created!

I require an admin menu tab which will link to the list of websites - Doesn't show when using the extended code below.

I require all forms of editing to be removed, however, still be able to click into each entry and view its contents (without being able to edit or update) - I think this is where the meta_cap features comes in, don't know how to apply it though.

Here is the full code I am using to declare my custom post type:

```
// Create Custom Post Type
protected function create_post_type() {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'custom_post_type'));
    add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'custom_post_type_caps'));
}

// Register Websites Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name'                  => __( 'Websites',                      'website-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Website',                       'website-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New',                       'website-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Website',               'website-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Website',                  'website-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Website',                   'website-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Website',                  'website-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Websites',               'website-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No websites found',             'website-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No websites found in Trash',    'website-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Website:',               'website-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Websites',                      'website-textdomain' )
    );

    $capabilities = array(
        'publish_posts'         => 'publish_websites',
        'edit_posts'            => 'edit_websites',
        'edit_others_posts'     => 'edit_others_websites',
        'delete_posts'          => 'delete_websites',
        'delete_others_posts'   => 'delete_others_websites',
        'read_private_posts'    => 'read_private_websites',
        'edit_post'             => 'edit_website',
        'delete_post'           => 'delete_website',
        'read_post'             => 'read_website'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'website',
        'capabilities'          => $capabilities,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'supports'              => array('title', 'custom-fields')
    );

    register_post_type('website', $args);
    //register_post_type('website', ['public' => true, 'label' => 'Websites']);
}

function custom_post_type_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $admins = get_role('administrator');

    $admins->add_cap('edit_website');
    $admins->add_cap('delete_website');
    $admins->add_cap('read_website');
}
```

A lot of things are commented out as I know that it works, the posts are created and can be accessed in a wp_query loop. I am just unable to get any other of the requirements on the list above ticked off so was attempting to dumb the code down a bit in the hopes I had just overcomplicated it.

If I use this line:

```
register_post_type('website', ['public' => true, 'label' => 'Websites']);
```

The post type is created and a menu tab appears in the admin left hand menu. But then I am unable to add any other criteria from the list above.

I have read and appreciate there are numerous other similar posts, but none are quite like this one, the combination of requirements are unique.